# Admob "Allow & block ads" shows no data

Tags: filter, admob, block

How do I filter my ads?

Before it was fine, I can select categories and stuff.
Now it became like this:

[image]

Comment: ... before what?

Comment: Works fine for me. AdMob.com>Monetize>All Apps>General Categories.